Split form with bound and unbound columns not allowing entries of multiple records (rows)
I have a couple of comboboxes in a split form with the following Property Sheet setting: [Split Form Datasheet] set to "Allow Edits" and [Split form Printing] set to "Form Only" which allows for data entry to the source table. Unfortunately for me, it only allows me to add one record (row). As soon as I start typing in the second record it changes every column of the first record to what I am adding to record line two.
Please I need some guidance with being able to enter multiple records either at the top or bottom Datasheet view to show more than one record and to be able to save multiple records entered during the activity.
On the "On CHANGE" event of cboProd I have the following:
Private Sub cboProd_Change()
   Me.ProdDesc = Me.cboProd.Column(1)
   Me.Quantity = Me.cboProd.Column(2)
   Me.Orders = Me.cboProd.Column(3)
   Me.AmountRem = Me.cboProd.Column(4)
End Sub

On the "On Change" event of  cboCust the following was used
Private Sub cboCust_Change()
   Me.CustID = Me.cboCust.Column(1)
   Me.CustName = Me.cboCust.Column(2)
   Me.CustGender = Me.cboCust.Column(3)
End Sub

Besides these two codes, there are just codes for close, save and search buttons.
I have tested several Property Sheet setting options.

Don't use VBA to populate UNBOUND textbox. All rows will show same value. Put expression in textbox ControlSource: =cboCust.Column(1).

Why is CustID in Column(1)? It should be in Column(0) and provide value of combobox.

Aside from that, Change event is not best choice to pull info from combobox columns - use AfterUpdate. But as already noted, don't use VBA in this case.

This question is similar to: How to populate the value of a Text Box based on the value in a Combo Box in MS Access 2007?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"Put expression in textbox ControlSource: =cboCust.Column(1)" That solved part of the issue. Rows are no longer showing same values. So, far it's working good. I will also move thw code from On Change to AfterUpdate....Thanks.
